# How to calculate number of selected in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get no of records also with the following SQL Server stored procedure. Can someone please let me know how I rewrite the following procedure?

```
    @PapCod AS VARCHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    SELECT 
        RTRIM(SA_ArticalCode) AS SupCode,
        RTRIM(SA_ArticalName) AS SupName
    FROM 
        Correspondent_Staff_Atricals
    WHERE 
        SA_PapCode = RTRIM(@PapCod)
END
```

Comment: Do you mean to get a quantity of selected rows inside of `SELECT` statement?

Comment: What will you want to rewrite? your question a little bit unclear

Comment: StepUp - Yes I need Quantity of Selected Rows inside of Select Statement.

Comment: @Mark please, see my reply. I've included a row with count of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use count(*) over()

```
SELECT 
  RTRIM(SA_ArticalCode) AS SupCode,
  RTRIM(SA_ArticalName) AS SupName,
  count(*) over() [count]
FROM 
  Correspondent_Staff_Atricals
WHERE 
  SA_PapCode = @PapCod -- no need to rtrim, the rows will be found anyway
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer is the most correct answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT` function.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    Correspondent_Staff_Atricals
WHERE 
    SA_PapCode = RTRIM(@PapCod)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union ALL` to append a row where you calculate number of rows:

```
SELECT RTRIM(SA_ArticalCode) as SupCode,
   RTRIM(SA_ArticalName) as SupName
   FROM Correspondent_Staff_Atricals
        WHERE SA_PapCode = RTRIM(@PapCod)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'RowsCount', COUNT(1)
FROM Correspondent_Staff_Atricals
        WHERE SA_PapCode = RTRIM(@PapCod)
```